# Android Paging 3 library, grouping items

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

We are developing a chat application.
If messages contain images, and they come one after another, we in adapter group these images in one message.

**Question 1**

In the database, and in the rest of API we have these messages separately, but in the adapter, we group them to display to the user as one big message with small icons of images inside.

We want to implement a paging library to have the possibility to scroll to any message in history. Currently, we are using a `RemoteMediator<Int, Message>`, which makes requests to our server, and gets messages. To store these messages we are using `Room`, which returns `PagingSource<Int, Message>`. To display messages we are using `PagingDataAdapter`

Everything works well, the question is how we can implement this grouping images logic in Paging 3?
On what steps and when we can make this change and group message in one?

**Example**:

```
Message1_Text1 - Message2_Image1 - Message3_Image2 - Message4_Text2
```

After grouping, we should receive

```
Message1_Text1 - Message2_(Image1_Image2) - Message3_Text2
```

**Question 2**

Depending on what messages are `before` and `after` we display messages differently, for example, we display profile icon only on the first message, all other messages from the same user displayed without a profile icon.

We can change our data in `PagingData.map{}` but we don't have any information about before and after items.
How can be this achieved?

Comment: Transformations on top of PagingData only allow you iterate through one item at a time, so if you want to aggregate items, I would try a layered approach where RemoteMediator fetches next items and updates a in-memory cache / DB, that does the aggregation on insert and provides the aggregate items to Paging.

Answer (score 1):

I am using paging with Jetpack Compose, I got a way to access the `before` and `after` item, making it possible to finish some grouping work. This might be a dumb way, but it works:

Create a function like:

```
fun <T : Any> LazyListScope.itemsBeforeAndAfter(
    items: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(value: T?, beforeValue: T?, AfterValue: T?) -> Unit
) {
    items(
        count = items.itemCount,
        key = if (key == null) null else { index ->
            val item = items.peek(index)
            if (item == null) {
                index
            } else {
                key(item)
            }
        }
    ) { index ->
        val beforeValue = if (index - 1 < 0) null else items.peek(index - 1)
        val afterValue = if (index + 1 >= items.itemCount) null else items.peek(index + 1)
        itemContent(items[index], beforeValue, afterValue)
    }
}
```

Now we can access the values we need:

```
val lazyPagingItems = pagingDataFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
            LazyColumn() {
                itemsBeforeAndAfter(
                    items = lazyPagingItems,
                    key = { // your own key logic }) { value, beforeValue, AfterValue ->
                    // Do whatever you want here
                }
            }
```

In this way I broke the `PagingPlaceholderKey`, so don't forget to disable it:

```
Pager(
    PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 20,
        enablePlaceholders = false
    )
) { // pagingSource }
```